# Why removing second last element from arraylist remove method doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add("1");
l.add("2");
l.add("3");
l.add("4");
Iterator<String> itr = l.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String str = itr.next();
    if (str.equals("3")) {
        l.remove(str);
    }
}
```

Why does the above code **not** throw `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: A method specifically for removing elements from a list would be entirely useless if it threw a CME.

Comment: `@implSpecThe default implementation traverses all elements of the collection using its iterator. Each matching element is removed using Iterator.remove(). If the collection's iterator does not support removal then an UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown on the first matching element.` <- From the docs. This should answer it

Comment: With the updated code: it's simply an artefact of how `hasNext()` is implemented for `ArrayList`. Do not rely upon this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because the way the element is removed (as part of the removeIf impementation) is done via an Iterator object.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of [`ArrayList.Itr`'s `hasNext()` method is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java):

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    // ...

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }
```

where `cursor` is an instance field of the iterator, and `size` is the list's size.

So, if you invoke `remove()` on the second-last element, you decrease the `size`, but don't change `cursor`. Previously, `cursor == size - 1`; now, `cursor == size`.

Significantly, this `hasNext()` doesn't invoke the `checkForComodification()` method. As such, the while loop evaluates the `hasNext()`, finds it is false, and stops. (You can observe the same behavior with a for-each loop).

This is merely a quirk of the implementation of `ArrayList`, and not something that you should rely upon.